# Custom keyboard height and width not change in outer application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, custom-keyboard

Custom keyboard is properly working in my application but when i move to another app like reminder then do not change height and width of custom keyboard so, how to resolve this problem.

working my app on all iPhone device like this

[image]

when i open custom keyboard to another application like reminder then do not change height and width of custom keyboard like this

[image]